# Why the C++ linker doesn't complain about missing definitions of theses functions?

Tags: c++, c, external-links

I have written this code:

```
// print.h
#pragma once

#ifdef __cplusplus
#include <string>

void print(double);
void print(std::string const&);
extern "C"

#endif

void print();
```

And the source file:

```
// print.cxx
#include "print.h"
#include <iostream>

void print(double x){
  std::cout << x << '\n';
}

void print(std::string const& str){
   std::cout << str << '\n';
}

void print(){
   printf("Hi there from C function!");
}
```

And the driver program:

```
// main.cxx
#include "print.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(){

  print(5);
  print("Hi there!");
  print();

  std::cout << '\n';
}
```

When I compile:

```
gcc -c print.cxx && g++ print.o main.cxx -o prog
```

- The program works just fine but what matter me a lot is:

I compiled `print.cxx` using `gcc` which doesn't define the C++ version `print(double)` and `print(std::string)`. So I get `print.o` that contains only the definition of the C version of `print()`.

- When I used `G++` to compile and build the program I passed `print.o` to it along with the source file `main.cxx`. It  produces the executable and works fine but inside `main.cxx` I called the C++ versions of `print` (`print(double)` and `print(std::string)`) and these ones are not defined in `prnint.o` because it has been compiled using GCC and because of the macro `__cplusplus` (conditional compilation). So how come that the linker doesn't complain about missing definitions of those functions?? Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I compiled `print.cxx` using `gcc` which doesn't define the C++ version...

Not quite. `gcc` and `g++` both invoke the same compiler suite. And the suite [has a set of file extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html) it **automatically recognizes** as either C or C++. Your `*.cxx` files were all compiled as C++, which is the default behavior for that extension.

You can use the `-x` option to override the default behavior.

Comment: Ah OK! Thanks you've saved the day! So if the extension is `c` for example then the C++ versions won't compile? Thanks

Comment: @ItachiUchiwa - If the extension is `*.c` it will be treated as a C file, yes. And `void print(std::string const&)` will elicit an error.

Comment: Ok Thank you so much! I've changed the extension to `.c` and I get the errors as I guessed. Thank you.

Comment: "GNU Compiler Collection" rather than "GNU C Compiler." You're not the first person to misinterpret that acronym, and I doubt you'll be the last.